# Should I consider the paragraph just like a text or a block of text (theory)?

Tags: css, semantic-markup

Today I get a work and see a little strange format form **paragraphs** `<p></p>`.

```
#product p { 
    float: left;
    width: 513px;
}
```

The HTML is:
**Observations:**
- the image every have 270px, never more

```
<div id='product'>
    <h1>Product name</h1>
    <div class='img-product'>
        <img src='http://fakeimg.pl/270x270/' />
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>           
</div>
```

The result for this html/css is a image with 270px width in left of page, and a blank space right it.

- gist: https://gist.github.com/6549722/8321ac9097cfd4b0ad127e3f74fa86370119f43a
- html/css: http://dabblet.com/gist/6549722

## My question is

### Only theory, not practice (I know how to solve this problem, I'm just wondering if using the tag "p" is only targeting texts, ie, it should not be used as a block).

the correct thing is create a div, for example "description", and format them(as the positioning and size), and not to apply paragraph formatting such? Aiming at the paragraph in 99% of the time is just text.

I never see anyone format a paragraph like a div, or, I see, is in extremely specific case. Because, for me, paragraph is a text element, nothing more, so, the styles is for fonts, colors, line-height, etc.

*Sorry for my english*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The W3C Recommendation [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/cover.html#minitoc) says:

> [9.3.1 Paragraphs: the P element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)
>
> The P element represents a paragraph.

> [7.5.4 Grouping elements: the DIV and SPAN elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4)
>
> The DIV and SPAN elements, in conjunction with the id and class
>   attributes, offer a generic mechanism for adding structure to
>   documents. These elements define content to be inline (SPAN) or
>   block-level (DIV) but impose no other presentational idioms on the
>   content. Thus, authors may use these elements in conjunction with
>   style sheets, the lang attribute, etc., to tailor HTML to their own
>   needs and tastes.
>
> Suppose, for example, that we wanted to generate an HTML document
>   based on a database of client information. Since HTML does not include
>   elements that identify objects such as "client", "telephone number",
>   "email address", etc., we use DIV and SPAN to achieve the desired
>   structural and presentational effects.

If you've got an actual paragraph, use `P`, but if you're structuring something that's not a paragraph, use `DIV` or `SPAN`.  The choice of which *element* to use is semantic, and should be based on the content.  The choice of styling is orthogonal, really.  You can style your paragraphs or your divisions however you like; they're both block level elements.

You do make an interesting point about trying to keep paragraph styles specific to the text, and not for document formatting, but this is only possible if you already have higher level divisions that the paragraphs are inside.  If you don't, that wouldn't be an option.  I'm personally a fan of simpler structure than more complex structure, so if my paragraphs suffice and don't need to be in higher level divisions, I'd just put the styling on the paragraphs, rather than wrapping them in divisions.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted . Then paragraphs are just paragraphs and aren't responsible for the structure of the page. Thanks Joshua!

Comment: Can't argue with the W3C. +1

Answer (score 0):

You will need float the div containing image to left. DIV is a block level element and won't allow any other element to come beside it unless floated.

```
.img-product{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that, my question is about: should I consider the paragraph just like a text or a block of text; I mean paragraph is just for text, or can I use like a div?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#product p { 
    float: left;
    width: 513px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that, my question is about: should I consider the paragraph just like a text or a block of text; I mean paragraph is just for text, or can I use like a div?

Comment: Never ever use it like a div or span, its a paragraph for a reason. 
correct semantic mark-up means using elements for their intended purpose.
if you want to position it differently, wrap the P in a Span or Div and apply the position to the span or div.

Comment: @AaronHopkins The semantics is carried by the fact that it's a paragraph element.  As long as the paragraph element isn't being created just for positioning purposes, wouldn't positioning styling on the single paragraph (i.e., <p></p>) be cleaner than wrapping the paragraph in a div (i.e., <div><p></p></div>).  The styles can still be separated (e.g., <p class="pos-style format-style"></p> with two different classes), after all.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor,  It comes down to preference really, but for me paddings and margins on block level elements cause problems in floated divs, if your aiming for a complex layout with many floats, then it's easier to stick to a methodology you know will give expected results...

Comment: So that said. I call every floated div a container and position these in such a way as to reach my intended layout, I know that if I place a couple of p tags in said container, I can affect both with a padding-left on the div...

Comment: If I stick to this idialect then all my sites which ive marked up , follow the same pattern, which in the long term, makes the revisiting the css much easier. So divs always mean positioning to me. And p tags are always stripped of their paddings and margins as a matter of course...

Comment: @AaronHopkins I do think that the amount of intended reusability is important in this discussion.  E.g., if you're writing templates, or some CSS that will be used in all over a website, then it's probably easier to use some containers.  For a single one-off document, I try to keep things as simple as possible.  E.g., if a short document really is just a series of paragraphs, I see no reason not to use paragraph elements.  Perhaps the big difference is between the use cases of HTML/CSS as a document markup and as a web site design/layout tool.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I agree, and both arguments have dual prominence. I think it's important to be able to make an informed choice based on reusability over strict semantics. CSS is a black art, and what with cross browser compatibility,  a minefield. So to be informed is wise. +1 to the OP for asking the question.